# Database solution for multi-user uml-ish application

Tags: java, database, multi-user

I'm working on a Eclipse RCP-based application that will switch from single user local storage to multi-user database storage and are now considering what storage solution to use.

It's sort of UML with some minor additional data that will be stored, probably not that much traffic and we need to run the server on the clients networks since it's security related software.

Required:

- Java-bindings
- ORM-layer

Wanted features:

- Some form of notification when somebody else has updated something else in the model would be nice, either as an add-on or included.
- Locking models would be nice too, add-on or included.
- Conflict resolution when two people change the same parts, add-on or included.

Comment: software recommendations are explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic] (it's the same here as at Stack Overflow). See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487